# JWT is being converted from str to bytes on requests.post()

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, jwt

I am writing a Flask application in which I have a service that generates a JWT and passes this onto another service using requests.post(), after decoding it to 'UTF-8'.

While sending the JWT, I can see that the type is 'str'. However, on performing a json.loads() on the other service, I get an error that says

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Here is my code:

Service 1:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   token = jwt.encode({'message': 'Hello'}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
   # After this statement I am able to verify the type is str and not bytes
   token = token.decode('UTF-8')
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   url = 'someUrl'
   data = {"token": token}
   data = json.dumps(data)
   requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
   return 'Success'
```

Service 2:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
   data = json.loads(request.data)
   return 'Success'
```

Why do I get this error even though the type was converted to string ?

EDIT: I was able to successfully retrieve the token by passing it through header. But I would still like to know what caused this error.

Comment: Try to remove `token = token.decode('UTF-8')`

Comment: That gives me a 'not JSON serializable TypeError'. It needs to be decoded to 'UTF-8' before json.dumps

Comment: Changing `data = json.loads(request.data)` to `data = request.get_json()` could be a possible workaround.

Answer (score -1):

You could post it as JSON instead of data, and let the underlying library take care of it for you.

Service 1

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   token = jwt.encode({'message': 'Hello'}, app.config['SECRET_KEY']).decode('UTF-8')
   url = 'someUrl'
   data = {"token": token}
   requests.post(url, json=data)
   return 'Success'
```

Service 2

```
    data = request.get_json()
```